# A basic conditional probability question

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

**The problem:** Considering a couple, the probability of the man watching a specific TV program is 0.4, the probability of the woman watching the same program is 0.5, and the probability of the man watching any program that the woman is watching is 0.7.

Now what is the probability of the woman watching any program that the man is watching?

---

My textbook appears to have using the Bayes' formula in mind (the solution provided below), but to me this problem seems impossible to answer. Using the Bayes' formula we could get the probability of the woman watching *the exact program mentioned in the question*, when the man is watching it. And we can't just generalize it to any program as two of our probabilities are restricted to the specific program.

Is my thinking correct?

**The provided solution:** Having $M$ as the event of the man watching the mentioned program and $W$ as the event of the woman watching the mentioned program:

$P(W|M)=\frac{P(W)P(M|W)}{P(M)}=\frac{7}{8}$

Comment: Not enough information.  What if there are 1000 candidate shows?  10?  3?  Doesn't that change the calculation?

Comment: Not sure the question really makes sense.  Can you list all the possible events and their probabilities?

Comment: @lulu I can't state *all* of the events because that's all the question provides. But considering "X" as a specific program and "y" as a random program we have: P(the man watching X)=0.4,  P(the woman watching X)=0.4, P(man watching y|woman watching y)=0.7. And we're looking for P(woman watching y|man watching y). At least that's what I understand from the question.

Comment: I don't even understand the basic set up.  How many TV's does the couple have? Can they watch different programs?  Can they leave the TV(s) off?  I note that $.7+.4>1$ so there is clearly meant to be some dependencies here, but what they are, I can't guess.  I really don't think there is nearly enough information here to say anything.  If your text includes a solution, I suggest posting it.  That way we could at least reverse engineer the assumptions they intended you to make.

Comment: @lulu I provided the solution, which to be honest doesn't make any sense to me, as it doesn't even answer the question asked, even if we assume it's the correct approach.

Comment: Huh.  I guess they mean you to assume that there is only the one program.  That seems to be in conflict with the wording of the problem, but if you ignore that then the computation makes sense.

Comment: That is to say, given the official solution, I think the problem should read something like "There is a particular program on at a particular moment.  There is a $.4$ chance that a given man will be watching it, and a $.5$ chance that a given woman will be watching it.  Given that the woman is in fact watching it, there is a $.7$ chance that the man is also watching it.  Find the conditional probability that the woman is watching it, given that the man is."

Comment: @lulu It's not the first time, and being a beginner all these "assumptions/mistakes" make me wonder whether I'm doing something wrong. I wish I could get rid of this textbook... Thanks anyways!

Comment: I should say:  this is often a problem with introductory texts in probability and combinatorics.  In what I assume to be an effort to make the problems sound more like "real life", they phrase things so vaguely that you can't really guess what they have in mind.  That said, this particular example seems a bit worse than most.